# 4.15 - Exercise - Mathematical Logic - Ebbinghaus

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

First, I will present the notations of the exercise $4.15$, which can be founded at the bottom of the page $37$ of Ebbinghaus's Mathematical Logic:

[image]

Now, the question:

[image]

I know that it's necessary to prove doing induction by S-terms and I can see clearly how to prove if the S-term $t$ is a constant or is a $n$-ary function 
 $f$ applied on $t_1, \cdots, t_n$ S-terms (it's basically by definition of direct product of the S-structures). My doubts are how to prove the base step if $t = x$ is a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

We have that : $\text{var}(t) \subset \{ v_0,\ldots, v_{n-1} \}$.

Thus, for the base case : $t := v_0$ we must have :

> $t^{\mathfrak A}[g_0]=\langle \ t^{\mathfrak A_i}[g_0(i)] \ \mid \ i \in I \ \rangle$.

And this is trivial because the "object" $g_0$ of the *direct product* $\mathfrak A$ is an element of the domain $\Pi_{i \in I} A_i$, i.e. a "sequence" $\langle \ g_0(i) \in A_i \ \mid \ i \in I \ \rangle$.

Comment: I think I understand, it's because $t^{\mathcal{U}}[g_0] = \mathcal{I}(v_0) = \beta(v_0) = g_0 \in \prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{U_i}$, but this element of a product of models is $g_0 = \langle g_0(i) \ ; \ i \in I \rangle$, but $g_0(i) = \mathcal{I}(v_0) =  t^{\mathcal{U_i}}[g_0]$, where $g_0(i) \in A_i$ is an interpretation of $v_0$ in $A_i$, then $t^{\mathcal{U}}[g_0] = \mathcal{I}(v_0) = \beta(v_0) = g_0 = \langle g_0(i) \ ; \ i \in I \rangle = \langle t^{\mathcal{U_i}}[g_0] \ ; \ i \in I \rangle$. Is this, isn't it?

Comment: @George - yes; we have that the interpretation "commutes" i.e. the int of the *term* $t$ in $\mathfrak A$ must be an $i$-uple. How is it made ? considering the int of $t$ in every $\mathfrak A_i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a little confuse for me work with a product of S-structures yet, but I understand now.

Comment: @George - consider $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^n$. What is an "object" in the first domain ? a real number. What is an "object" in the second one ? A point in the $n$-dimensions space with real coordinates.